# Inequality in Hanoi Open Mathematics Competition

Tags: inequality

$\frac{1}{bc} + \frac{1}{ab} + \frac{1}{ca} \geq 1$.
Prove $\frac{a}{bc} + \frac{c}{ab} + \frac{b}{ca} \geq 1$, where
$a,b,c$ are positive real numbers

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac{1}{bc},y=\frac{1}{ab},z=\frac{1}{ca}$. The question becomes given $x+y+z\geq1$ , prove $\frac{x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{yz}}+\frac{y\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{xz}}+\frac{z\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{xy}}=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{\sqrt{xyz}}\geq 1$.

From Cauchy-Schwarz $3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq(x+y+z)^2$ 
From AM-GM $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq 3(xyz)^{2/3}$

$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{\sqrt{xyz}}=\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/4}(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/4}}{\sqrt{xyz}}\geq\frac{3^{3/4}\sqrt{xyz}3^{-1/4}\sqrt{x+y+z}}{\sqrt{xyz}}\geq \sqrt{3}\geq 1$$

Comment: There is no need for anything this big, see my answer.